# Failed to Find Keys at Zone Apex

Tags: dns, bind

I'm trying to create a signed zone file, but previous examples are not working for me. See below

```
[root@dnsserv1 named]# dnssec-keygen -r /dev/random -a RSASHA1 -b 1024 -n ZONE example.edu
Generating key pair.........................+++++ ..............................................+++++ 
example.edu.+005+56778

# Create KSK
[root@dnsserv1 named]# dnssec-keygen -r /dev/random -a RSASHA1 -b 1024 -n ZONE -f KSK example.edu
Generating key pair........................................................................+++++ ..........+++++ 
example.edu.+005+27182

[root@dnsserv1 named]#  dnssec-signzone -o example.edu -k  'example.edu.+005+56778' example.edu.zone  'example.edu.+005+27182.key'
dnssec-signzone: warning: example.edu.zone:1: no TTL specified; using SOA MINTTL instead
dnssec-signzone: fatal: failed to find keys at the zone apex: not found
```

This "failed to find keys at the zone apex: not found" error doesn't seem like it's common. If I search for it on Google, almost nothing comes up. Did I forget to do something? I've tried many different variants on what's shown above.

Comment: Your question is offtopic here as not related to programming. But you might want to first make sure to fully understand DNS, before starting DNSSEC. The error message simply tells you that your zonefile currently is incorrect, as it is missing DNSKEY records. See https://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.19/doc/arm/html/chapter7.html for a start; you may want to let bind manage keys on your behalf.

Comment: " I've tried many different variants on what's shown above." specially in case of DNSSEC, doing blind attempts until it works is certainly not a good idea. You need to fully understand how DNSSEC works, what are KSKs and ZSKs, how a DS works and where it is, what is automated and what needs to be done manually, etc.